# user account creation date in LDAP

Tags: bash, ldap

I would like to write a shell script to do the following , would advise how to make it ? very thanks

1. Connect LDAP server ( Id : user , password : pass )
2. check the field `user_account_create_date` in the LDAP server, the format of data in this field is `ABC20130922` (September 22, 2013)
3. find the record in this field to check last 8 digits ,

Pseudocode:

```
   if the date is within 7 days: # account is created within 7 days
       then do
            ...
       else do
            ...
```

I have a script as below which connect ldap, and check if the user account is created within 7 days ( the script is not complete yet)

```
timestamp = date --date="-7 days" +%Y%m%d%k%m%SZ

ldapsearch -h 192.168.1.100 -p 389 -D cn=admin,o=services -w pass -x "(&(objectclass=*)(createTimestamp>=$timestamp))"

then
```

What I hope to do now is to modify the above script so that `createTimestamp` get the creation date string which can be used to compare with timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Something close to this should work:

```
ndays=7
timestamp=`date --date="-$ndays days" +'%Y%m%d'"100000Z"`

ldapsearch -x -LLL -h yourhost.yourdoamin.com -p 389 -b "ou=people,dc=yourdomain,dc=com" -D cn=admin,....,dc=yourdomain,dc=com -w yourpassword "(&(objectclass=inetorgperson)(modifytimestamp>=$timestamp))" modifytimestamp
```

I used modifyTimeStamp for testing as no one had been created lately on my home system.

-jim

Comment: thx for reply , what is modifyTimeStamp ? is it a field in LDAP ?

Comment: An LDAP attribute that according to RFC 4512, "Servers SHOULD maintain the 'creatorsName', 'createTimestamp','modifiersName', and 'modifyTimestamp' attributes for all entries of the DIT."

Comment: He doesn't want modification time, he wants creation time.

Comment: So I assume he would substitute creationTimestampe for modifiyTimeStamp.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the timestamp has the correct syntax (generalized time). When using a value in an assertion (filter), the value must be the syntax of the attribute. Also, the `objectClass=*` component of the filter is not needed: all entries have at least one `objectClass`.